Can one prove directly that the language given by a regular grammar is the language given by some regular expression?
The let $L$ be a language. The following are equivalent:

$L$ is given by a deterministic or non-deterministic finite accepter.
$L$ is given by a regular grammar.
$L$ is given by a regular expression.

The proof of this equivalence in Linz' Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata consists in showing $(1\iff 2)$ and $(1\iff 3)$. Most of the proof is fine, yet the step $(1\implies 3)$ by means of generalized transition graphs is rather tedious.
So I wondered: is there a direct proof of $(2\implies 3)$? That is, a proof that does not rely on finite automata.
I understand the answer may be a simple "no", or a "yes, but the proof becomes even more tedious", yet I found it worthwhile to check.

Let $G = (\Sigma, V, P, S)$ a context-free grammar.
Let us start with some simple statements:
Lemma 1: $G$ is right-regular (rules $X\to \varepsilon$, $X\to a$ and $X\to aY$ only) if and only if it is equivalent to a strict right-regular grammar (rules $X\to \varepsilon$ and $X\to aY$ only).
Proof: Add a variable $\mathcal{E}$, a rule $\mathcal{E}\to \varepsilon$, and replace each $X\to a$ with $X\to a\mathcal{E}$.
Lemma 2: If $G$ is right-regular, $X\in V$ and $\beta\in (\Sigma \cup V)^*$ such that $X\Rightarrow^* \beta$, then $\beta$ contains at most one variable. If it contains one variable, it is at the end of the word.
Lemma 3: If $G$ is right-regular, $X\in V$ and $u\in \Sigma^*$, then $X\Rightarrow^* u$ if and only if $X\Rightarrow^* uY$, with some $Y$ such that $Y\to \varepsilon$ is a production rule.
Theorem: If $G$ is regular (right-regular or left-regular), then $L(G)$ is regular.
Proof: Assume first that $G$ is right-regular. Using Lemma 1, we can suppose that it is strict right-regular.
Let $V = \{X_1, X_2, …, X_n\}$, such that $X_1 = S$ (the starting variable). For $i, j\in [\![1, n]\!]$ and $k\in [\![0,n]\!]$, denote $L_{ij}^{(k)}$ the language of words $u\in \Sigma^*$ such that:

$X_i \Rightarrow^* uX_j$
any intermediate word $\beta$ appearing in the derivation does not contain any $X_{\ell}$ with $\ell> k$.

Let us prove by induction that $L_{ij}^{(k)}$ is regular for all $i, j, k$:

if $k = 0$, then $L_{ij}^{(k)} = \{a\in \Sigma \mid X_i \to aX_j\in P\}\cup \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\varepsilon &\text{if } i=j\\ \emptyset & \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$ is regular;

assume the result for any $\ell < k$, for some fixed $k>0$. Then $u\in L_{ij}^{(k)}$ if and only if:

$u \in L_{ij}^{(k-1)}$

or there is a derivation:
$$X_i \Rightarrow^* u_0X_k \Rightarrow^* u_0u_1X_k \Rightarrow^* … \Rightarrow^* u_0u_1…u_{m-1}X_k \Rightarrow^* u_0u_1…u_{m-1}u_mX_j$$
such that no $X_{\ell}$ with $\ell \geqslant k$ appears in the words of the intermediate derivations.
By definition, $u_0 \in L_{ik}^{(k-1)}$, $u_m\in L_{kj}^{(k-1)}$ and for $0 < \ell < m$, $u_{\ell}\in L_{kk}^{(k-1)}$.


That means that $L_{ij}^{(k)} = L_{ij}^{(k-1)}\cup L_{ik}^{(k-1)}\left(L_{kk}^{(k-1)}\right)^*L_{kj}^{(k-1)}$ is indeed regular.


Finaly, let $V_{\varepsilon} = \{X \in V\mid X\to\varepsilon\in P\}$. Then $L(G) = \bigcup\limits_{X_j\in V_{\varepsilon}} L_{1j}^{(n)}$ is regular.
Now if $G$ is left-regular instead, a simple way to get the result is to notice that if you replace each $X\to Ya$ with $X\to aY$, you get a right-regular grammar that describes the mirror language. Since the mirror language of a regular language is regular, $L(G)$ is regular.
Note that, though I did not use any automaton in the proof, it is directly inspired by the McNaughton-Yamada's algorithm.

This is great! When you say "does not contain any $X_l$ for $l>k$" you are excluding only the first and last steps of the derivation (that include $X_i$ and $X_j$), right?

Also, in the inductive step, how do you know that $u\in L^{(k)}{ij}\setminus L^{(k)}{ij}$ means there is a derivation $X_i \Rightarrow^* u_0 X_k \Rightarrow^* \cdots \Rightarrow^* u_0u_1\ldots u_{m-1}X_k \Rightarrow^* u_0u_1\ldots u_m Xj$ for (I'm guessing) $u = u_0u_1\ldots u_m$?

For your first comment, the answer is yes (that my meaning for "intermediate word"). For your second comment, I use the fact that since $u \notin L_{ij}^{(k-1}}$, the variable $X_k$ may appear one or multiple times in the derivation, and I use the lemma 2 to find the pattern for the intermediate words.

Here's a solution using language equations.
With every grammar $G$ with terminals $\Sigma$, non-terminals $V = \{S_1, S_2, ..., S_n\}$ and start variable $S_1$ we can associate a system of equations over a set of variables $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$.
For $1 \leq i \leq n$ set
$$X_i = \alpha_1' + \alpha_2' + ... + \alpha_m'$$
given $S_i \to \alpha_1 | \alpha_2 | ... | \alpha_m$.
Here $+$ denotes set union and $\alpha_j'$ denotes $\alpha_j$ where all occurrences of non-terminals $S_k$ are substituted by $X_k$.
It can be seen, that $X_i = L(S_i)$ is a solution to this system.

Example:
Given $G$ where
$$
\begin{align*}
  S_1 \to & bS_1 | aS_2 | bS_2 \\
  S_2 \to & aS_2 | \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$
we have the associated system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
  X_1 & = bX_1 + aX_2 + bX_2 \\
  & = bX_1 + (a + b)X_2  \\
  X_2 & = aX_2 + \varepsilon \\
  & = \emptyset X_1 + aX_2 + \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$

As in the example, you can see that every equation in the system of equations of a right-regular grammar has the form
$$X_i = \sum_{j = 1}^n L_{i, j}X_j \text{ or } X_i = \sum_{j = 1}^n L_{i, j}X_j + \varepsilon \tag{1}$$
where $L_{i, j}$ is a regular expression with $\varepsilon \notin L_{i, j}$.
We will try to solve these equations.
Here's an important result called Arden's rule:

Arden's rule: The equation $X = LX + R$ has a smallest solution $L^*R$. Moreover, if $\varepsilon \notin L$ then $L^*R$ is the only solution.

Now for the actual proof.

Theorem: A system of equations where each equation has the form in (1) has a unique solution for $X_1$ that can be written as a regular expression.

Proof:
Suppose we have the system of equations for a right-regular grammar with variables $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$.

If $n = 1$, then either $X_1 = L_{1, 1}X_1$ or $X_1 = L_{1, 1}X_1 + \varepsilon$.
So using Arden's rule $X_1$ has one of two unique solutions, either $X_1 = \emptyset$ or $X_1 = (L_{1, 1})^*$.
$L_{1,1}$ is a regular expression, so $(L_{1,1})^*$ is one as well.
If $N > 1$ and $X_n = \sum_{j = 1}^n L_{n, j}X_j = L_{n, n}X_n + \sum_{j = 1}^{n - 1} L_{n, j}X_j$, then using Arden's rule we get the unique solution
$$X_n = (L_{n, n})^*\sum_{j = 1}^{n - 1} L_{n, j}X_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{n - 1} (L_{n, n})^*L_{n, j}X_j.$$
Now substituting this solution into the equations of $X_i, i < n$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
X_i & = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}L_{i, j}X_j + \sum_{j = 1}^{n - 1} (L_{n, n})^*L_{n, j}X_j\ (+\ \varepsilon) \\
& = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}(L_{i, j} + (L_{n, n})^*L_{n, j})X_j\ (+\ \varepsilon) \\
\end{align*}
$$
Since $L_{i, j}, L_{n, n}$ and $L_{n, j}$ are regular expressions, so is $L_{i, j} + (L_{n, n})^*L_{n, j}$.
Also, since $\varepsilon \notin L_{i, j}, L_{n, n}, L_{n, j}$ we have $\varepsilon \notin L_{i, j} + (L_{n, n})^*L_{n, j}$.
So we're left with a system of equations with $n - 1$ variables still satisfying $(1)$.
The case where $n > 1$ and $X_n = \sum_{j = 1}^n L_{n, j}X_j + \varepsilon$ is analogous.

Using induction over $n$, we obtain a unique solution to the system that can be written as a regular expression. $\square$
As a corollary it follows, that the system of equations of a right regular grammar has a unique solution s.t. $X_1 = L(S_1)$ that can be written as a regular expression.

Example (continued):
We have the system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
  X_1 & = bX_1 + (a + b)X_2 \\
  X_2 & = aX_2 + \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$
Using Arden's rule it follows that
$$X_2 = a^*\varepsilon = a^*$$
Substituting $X_2$ in $X_1$ we get
$$X_1 = bX_2 + (a + b)a^*$$
Using Arden again we get
$$X_1 = b^*(a + b)a^* = b^*a^+ + b^+a^*$$
which is the unique solution to the system and a regular expression for $L(G)$.


There is not much difference (technically) between a nonderterministic automaton and a linear grammar. A single step from state to state reading a letter is equivalent to a nonterminal generating a letter and a new nonterminal. That is why $(1 \iff 2)$ is not very complicated.
From automaton to regular expression or the other way around is less obvious. A regular expression has no explicit states.
As FSA and linear grammar are related in a straightforward way, a simple proof of $(2\implies 3)$ can be easily translated into such a proof for  $(1\implies 3)$. Hence I believe there is not much to win here.
